# Create a numeric variable in a dataframe based upon mean of another variable and a factor

Tags: r

Ok so I have what is very likely a simple question albeit one that I have found hard to pose (that is likely the root of the problem).

If I have the following example data:

```
    V1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
    factor <- factor(V1)
    V2 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
    V3 <- c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)
    test <- data.frame(factor,V2,V3)
```

How might I go about generating another variable, lets say V4, that is the mean of V3 for each level of factor? I can get the mean values using for example tapply:

```
    tapply(test$V3, test$factor, FUN=mean)
```

which in this case would result in 30 and 80 respectively but I want this to form a repeating variable the length of the relevant factor level as follows:

```
      factor V2  V3 v4
   1       1  1  10 30
   2       1  2  20 30
   3       1  3  30 30
   4       1  4  40 30
   5       1  5  50 30
   6       2  6  60 80
   7       2  7  70 80
   8       2  8  80 80
   9       2  9  90 80
   10      2 10 100 80
```

Any suggestions and solutions would be welcome along with how better to phrase the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ave` instead of `tapply`:

```
within(test, {
  V4 <- ave(V3, factor, FUN = mean)
})
   factor V2  V3 V4
1       1  1  10 30
2       1  2  20 30
3       1  3  30 30
4       1  4  40 30
5       1  5  50 30
6       2  6  60 80
7       2  7  70 80
8       2  8  80 80
9       2  9  90 80
10      2 10 100 80
```

The construct is very similar to the way you've used `tapply`. I've used `within` for two reasons: (1) to save some typing, and (2) to allow us to automatically create the new column.

---

The `data.table` package has some very convenient syntax for these types of operations:

```
> library(data.table)
data.table 1.8.8  For help type: help("data.table")
> DT <- data.table(test)
> DT[, V4 := mean(V3), by = factor]
> DT
    factor V2  V3 V4
 1:      1  1  10 30
 2:      1  2  20 30
 3:      1  3  30 30
 4:      1  4  40 30
 5:      1  5  50 30
 6:      2  6  60 80
 7:      2  7  70 80
 8:      2  8  80 80
 9:      2  9  90 80
10:      2 10 100 80
```

---

Not to overwhelm the reader, but there are *LOTS* of ways to do this. Here are two more solutions in base R (though much less efficient than the alternatives already shared).

`aggregate`

```
merge(test, 
      setNames(aggregate(V3 ~ factor, test, mean), 
               c("factor", "V4")), all = TRUE)
```

Making use of your `tapply` output.

```
temp <- tapply(test$V3, test$factor, FUN=mean)
temp <- data.frame(V4 = temp)
merge(test, temp, by.x = "factor", by.y = "row.names", all = TRUE)
```

Comment: Excellent that is great thanks as well as extraordinarily quick!

Comment: +1 for the solution with base R. I tend to always forget about `ave`.

Comment: @juba -- There are now *3* base solutions :)

Comment: +1, but also leave something for the rest of us mortals too! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `plyr` :

```
R> ddply(test, .(factor), transform, V4=mean(V3))
   factor V2  V3 V4
1       1  1  10 30
2       1  2  20 30
3       1  3  30 30
4       1  4  40 30
5       1  5  50 30
6       2  6  60 80
7       2  7  70 80
8       2  8  80 80
9       2  9  90 80
10      2 10 100 80
```

Comment: I think between the two of us we have a good collection now. +1

Comment: @AnandaMahto I added an answer with `data.table`. I'm surprised Arun didn't post one already :)